# Does DiRT 1 have USB game controller support, and if so how can I activate it?

Tags: controllers, dirt

I am playing DiRT 1.

Since it's a racing game, I'd like to use my (pretty old) plug n play gamepad - it's a Microsoft Sidewinder of some kind.

However, I cannot seem to find a way to select a gamepad in the options.

Is it possible to use it, or am I stuck to the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found no way of doing this.

However, I am now using [XPadder](http://xpadder.com/) which is a neat little program that maps gamepad input to keyboard input, thus allowing it to be recognised by DiRT.

There is a fully free (rather than just shady free versions of XPadder) alternative for this: [JoyToKey](http://www.electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm).